# Opposite of preserve_most calling-convention attribute?

Tags: c++, clang, x86-64, compiler-optimization, calling-convention

I'm a beginner and working on compilers and would like to apply one attribute to remove MOVAPS instruction from the assembly.

Is there any attribute in C++ which performs the opposite function of [clang's `preserve_most`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#preserve-most)?

Comment: Are you talking about the overriding the Windows x64 calling convention for functions that currently compile to save/restore xmm6..15?  `__attribute__((sysv_abi))` where all the vector registers are call-clobbered could avoid *those* uses for `movaps`, but a `ms_abi` function that calls a `sysv_abi` function must itself save/restore the vector regs, but it could possibly help if the call is inside a loop.  Obviously none of this is part of ISO C++11, so that tag isn't really relevant.

Comment: Or wait a minute, `preserve_most` doesn't have any call-preserved vector regs that would need `movaps` to save/reload in the callee.  Maybe you're talking about `movaps` save/restore in the caller, around a call *because* of that?  `preserve_all` is literally the opposite as far as x/ymm regs.  `ms_abi` has some of each, but also other requirements like shadow space, although its call-clobbered regs are a subset of those in the x86-64 SysV ABI, so it's not a big burden for callers. (unlike the reverse).

Comment: Anyway, can't really answer without knowing which MOVAPS instructions you're trying to avoid in which kind of case.  Obviously just calling-convention choices won't remove all of them; compilers will still freely use MOVAPS to copy 16-byte structs or initializers unless you compile with `-mno-sse -mno-mmx` (or `-fgeneral-regs-only` for a kernel).

Comment: At the beginning of a function in assembly code, MOVAPS save  and end of the assembly MOVAPS reload code will be there right, I was talking about to remove those instructions

Comment: Are you talking about Windows x64, then?  For functions that use a lot of XMM registers and need to save some of XMM6..15?  Only Windows x64 has to do that, not x86-64 System V.  And even then, it's not normal for most functions to do that.  It would be best to edit the question with an example (e.g. C++ source and the resulting asm from clang -O2, and a link to it on https://godbolt.org/ if possible.  Unless it only happens with clang targeting Windows.)

Comment: Yes, Im talking about x64. 


 vmovaps xmmword ptr [rbp + 384], xmm14  # 16-byte Spill
 ---
 vmovdqa xmmword ptr [rbp + 256], xmm6   # 16-byte Spill
 .seh_savexmm xmm6, 384

      .........

       vmovaps xmm6, xmmword ptr [rbp + 256]   # 16-byte Reload
 vmovaps xmm7, xmmword ptr [rbp + 272]   # 16-byte Reload
 ----
 vmovaps xmm14, xmmword ptr [rbp + 384]  # 16-byte Reload

this is the assembly

Comment: First of all, [edit] your question where the code is readable, unlike in a comment.  And then yeah, just use a calling convention like `sysv_abi` with no call-preserved XMM registers if that's what you want.  An ms_abi function calling a sysv_abi function must itself save/restore those XMM regs, but only once per invocation, so if the call to a sysv_abi function is in a loop, that's fine. You want that to happen less often, not as many times as the original function you care about gets called, which might mean applying it to other wrapper functions.

Comment: Also, `preserve_most` already has all 16 X/YMM registers as call-clobbered, so you could just use that for the leaf function you call in a loop.  Unless you're talking about vmovaps instructions in its parent?  Yeah, that's unavoidable *somewhere* if you have any ms_abi functions (the default on Windows) that call other calling-conventions.

Comment: Ok. I got your points. So how can we simply apply preserve_most for a function. Let's say int foo(){ return (sqrt(100);)}. Where do we apply this preserve_most

Comment: Why would you want to apply `preserve_most` to a function that returns a compile-time constant `int`?  You wouldn't apply it at all if you want efficiency.  Or you'd use `preserve_all` so the caller knows it doesn't modify any XMM registers, although a debug build that doesn't inline `sqrt` could then waste instructions.  If you show a real example of a case where you get XMM save/restore in a hot path (e.g. a function and its caller), it would be possible to give a useful answer.